# Blender 3.1 assign TOGGLE shortcut to "lock camera to view"?

Tags: shortcut

How to make a toggle shortcut?
The Right Click over "Camera to View" "Change shortcut" used is: Shift+Ctrl+Alt+(numpad) 0
Want to press the same combo to able/disable.
currently it only enables it, Have to go back to the the checkbox to disable.

Also with the Camera selected the View> "Camera to View" checkbox does something different than the Shorcut created above. It just Locks the Camera and Pans the scene.

Comment: You could add it to the Quick menu.

Answer (score 3):

#### Assign TOGGLE shortcut: Lock camera to view

1. Go to Keymap > 3D view (Global)

[image]

2. Add New

```
wm.context_toggle
```

3. Context Attributes:

```
space_data.lock_camera
```

[image]

Comment: What is the "F22"?

Comment: Blender support F1 ~ F24, you can choose the keys you want.